# PHP: Only List Items With Quantity Value Greater Than 0 In If Statement

Tags: php

'Ello

I'm trying to get the items from a client populated "order form" to ONLY list the items that the client has designated a quantity value of 1 or more to be sent as a Purchase Order receipt that is generated and sent via email once they hit Submit.

Here's what I have so far on that part:

```
$i = 1;
$imax = 4;

echo "Products<br />";
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------<br />";

while ($i <= $imax) {

$itemqty = ${'qty'.$i};
$itempn = ${'pn'.$i};
$itemdesc = ${'desc'.$i};
$itemprice = ${'value'.$i};
$itemtotalprice = ${'elinetotal'.$i};

    if ($itemqty !== 0) {
            echo $itemqty . " x " . $itemdesc . " (" . $itempn . ") @ $" . $itemprice . " ea. = $" . $itemtotalprice . "<br />";
    }
$i++;
}
```

It lists everything correctly, except it doesn't disregard the items with a value of 0. It'll list them like this:

```
Products
-------------------------------------------------------------
0 x Item #1 Description (HOSE-12) @ $155.00 ea. = $0.00
5 x Item #2 Description (GAUGE-2) @ $51.00 ea. = $255.00
0 x Item #3 Description (PTC) @ $0.70 ea. = $0.00
10 x Item #4 Description (PT-234R) @ $15.94 ea. = $159.40
```

It may be the easiest fix, but can anyone shed some light on this? I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Instead of using dynamic variables, why not just store each qty, pn, desc, etc in an array?

Comment: If `$itemqty` is a string (which values from a database normally are), then `!== 0` will yield true. Try `!== '0'`.

Comment: I'm with @Phil - any time you think you need dynamic variable names, you're probably well down a path that is fraught with potential bugs & poor scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial guess is `$itemqty` is the string `'0'`. Try using the *not equal* operator, eg

```
if ($itemqty != 0)
```

instead of the *not identical* operator, ie `!==`

Otherwise, you could try casting the `$itemqty` assignment as an integer, eg

```
$itemqty = (int) ${'qty'.$i};
```

Comment: This was exactly what was wrong with it. Such a simple fix. Thank you very much!